Specify the Method for `NIntegrate` to evaluate a integral of special functions
I have a special function as
$$f(x)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \, _2F_3\left(\frac{5}{12},\frac{11}{12};\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6};-\frac{4
   x^6}{729}\right)}{\pi }-\frac{x^2 \, _3F_4\left(\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{5}{4};\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3};-\frac{4
   x^6}{729}\right)}{3 \pi }+\frac{4 x \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{2}{3};-\frac{x^6}{729}\right) \sin \left(\frac{2
   x^3}{27}\right)}{9 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{4 x^4 \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{5}{3};-\frac{x^6}{729}\right) \cos \left(\frac{2
   x^3}{27}\right)}{243 \sqrt{3}}$$
and it can be generated in mathematica by
f[x_] = Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, 
  Integrate[
    Exp[I x t - Abs[t]^(3/2)]/(2 \[Pi]), {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] // FullSimplify]


(Gamma[5/3] HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 11/12}, {1/3, 1/2, 5/6}, -((4 x^6)/
   729)])/\[Pi] - (
x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 1, 5/4}, {2/3, 5/6, 7/6, 4/3}, -((4 x^6)/
   729)])/(3 \[Pi]) + (1/(243 Sqrt[3]))
4 x (x^3 Cos[(2 x^3)/27] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[5/
     3, -(x^6/729)] + 
   27 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2/3, -(x^6/729)] Sin[(2 x^3)/27])


Actually, f[x] is just the Fourier Transform of Exp[- Abs[t]^(3/2)], so f[x] satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx=1$.
However, when I tried to use NIntegrate to check the above integral like
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 200]

it returns a lot of warnings and cannot give me the actual result as 1.. I tried different options of Method, but none of them worked. My question is: how to specify the options of NIntegrate to return a pure result of 1. with no warnings?

After extensive testing, I discovered the reason for the slow convergence of the integral and provided a solution.
Reason
Let's define the function
g[x_] := (Gamma[
      5/3]  HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 11/12}, {1/3, 1/2, 
       5/6}, -((4  x^6)/729)])/\[Pi] - (x^2  HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 
       1, 5/4}, {2/3, 5/6, 7/6, 
       4/3}, -((4  x^6)/729)])/(3  \[Pi]) + (1/(243  Sqrt[
        3])) 4  x  (x^3  Cos[(2  x^3)/
        27]  Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[5/3, -(x^6/729)] + 
     27  Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[
       2/3, -(x^6/729)]  Sin[(2  x^3)/27])

and its plot is like
Plot[g[x], {x, -10, 10}]


However, g[x] is a sum of several rapidly oscillating hypergeometric and trigonometric functions, we can see the fact by the following plot:
Plot[List @@ Expand@g[x] // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


g[x] approaches 0 as x becomes very large, but according to the definition of g[x], the calculation for large x involves summing and subtracting several very large numbers to obtain a very small number. This process can lead to precision loss, as shown in the following code:
g[100000.]
N[g[100000]]
N[g[100000], 5]
N[g[100000], 10]
N[g[100000], 100]


-0.578583
0.156916
9.4617*10^-14
9.461747913*10^-14
9.461747912505320825013234411217651754033813792256913801995613672156709212488413304394932523016940481*10^-14```


We can see that even N[g[100000]] leads to precision loss.
It is the precision loss of g[x] when x is very large leads to the slow convergence of the integral.
Solution
From the above test codes, we can see that Mathematica can perform precise calculations of g[x], but we need to find an appropriate method to implement automatic precise calculations in numerical integration. I found that setting the precision of x before passing the parameters to g[x] solves the problem, like
f[x_?NumericQ, n_] := Block[{x0 = SetPrecision[x, n]}, g[x0]]

NIntegrate[f[x, 30], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{1.03975, 1.}*)

It takes about 1 second to get a pure result of 1. on my computer.

Is the following result satisfactory?
NIntegrate[(Gamma[5/3]  HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 11/12}, {1/3, 1/2, 
   5/6}, -((4  x^6)/729)])/\[Pi] - (x^2  HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 
   1, 5/4}, {2/3, 5/6, 7/6, 4/3}, -((4  x^6)/729)])/(3  \[Pi]) + 
1/(243  Sqrt[3])  4   x   (x^3   Cos[(2  x^3)/
    27]   Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[5/3, -(x^6/729)] + 
 27   Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[
   2/3, -(x^6/729)]   Sin[(2  x^3)/27]), {x, -100, 100}] 


0.9996

and two warnings (not errors). I don't know good numerical methods for improper integrals.

You might split the integration range to help NIntegrate find the significant range.
Try (similar to user64494's answer)
NIntegrate[(Gamma[
       5/3] HypergeometricPFQ[{5/12, 11/12}, {1/3, 1/2, 
        5/6}, -((4 x^6)/729)])/\[Pi] - (x^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4, 1,
         5/4}, {2/3, 5/6, 7/6, 4/3}, -((4 x^6)/729)])/(3 \[Pi]) + 
   1/(243 Sqrt[
        3]) 4 x (x^3 Cos[(2 x^3)/27] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[
        5/3, -(x^6/729)] + 
      27 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[
        2/3, -(x^6/729)] Sin[(2 x^3)/27]), {x, Infinity, -1000, 1000, 
   Infinity}] // Quiet

which evaluates to  0.999992(2 Warnings)  and gives an error estimation.

The following high precision result rounds to exactly 1 in machine precision. I don't know how close to 1 you would like to have, but since you're using NIntegrate, I assume you do not expect to actually get exactly 1 (you asked for "a pure result of 1.).
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, PrecisionGoal -> 16, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 200, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]
(*
0.99999999999999999999999999999999999998431463548367428644146409178423\
6441967070773735434458424625657757952996253749962481733456109758408975\
051046056278318478921163253580233777481289962607017609795977423
*)

% // N
% - 1
(*
1.
0.
*)


Works with Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 9} works, too.

Unfortunately, NIntegrate[f[x]+10^-99*Log[RealAbs[x]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, PrecisionGoal -> 16,   WorkingPrecision -> 200, Method -> "Trapezoidal"] produces 0.999999999999999999999999999999999999984314635483674286441464091801738254538443588828704149023678346077548415952581695236144527826939192462426433965669978572946846554020101858678818784565312379267052323 though the integral is divergent.

For +10^-59*Log[RealAbs[x]] the result is 1.00000000000000014568414760657042641432463732486163813938831631352125682975965715268028973136917485694458356987597513597758362791523194464039572798603587556556417816335262393367958051577625119107311991.
